# Making POST query on PlayServiceCall

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I have a PlayServiceCall that is supposed to handle the GraphQL POST query. The code is below -

```
override def restPostCall: PlayServiceCall[String, String] = PlayServiceCall { request =>

    Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
      val query = (request.body \ "query").as[String]
      val operation = (request.body \ "operationName").asOpt[String]
      val variables = (request.body \ "variables").toOption.map {
        case obj: JsObject => obj
        case _ => Json.obj()
      }

      QueryParser.parse(query) match {
        // query parsed successfully, time to execute it!
        case Success(queryAst) ⇒
          executeGraphQLQuery(queryAst, operation, variables getOrElse Json.obj())

        // can't parse GraphQL query, return error
        case Failure(error: SyntaxError) ⇒
          Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.obj("error" → error.getMessage)))
      }
    }
  }
```

The code is same as the one explained in the Getting Started page on Sangria website and also the code of [example project on Github by Sangria](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-playground/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala). Here graphqlBody method handles the POST request of GraphQL.

When I send the GraphQL query by **POST** method it gives following error -

```
For request 'POST /graphql' [Invalid Json: Unrecognized token 'query': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@10f6774; line: 1, column: 7]]
```

Can anyone please help how to send the GraphQL query by POST method with Sangria.

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I just found the solution. The query is still needed to be sent in JSON format like this

```
{
"query" : "query HeroAndFriends { hero {name friends { name }}}"
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I form the query JSON like that from Sangria?

Comment: I didn't understand your question!